# How can I access the django-admin page and extend it?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-admin

I'll put this in a very simple way.
I would want to access django-admin HTML of a particular page.

Here is the image:

[image]

of the page I want to access.

The Path is as
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/listings/listing/12/change/

I just want to add my custom html button to it which will introduce a field once clicked.

How would I extend the html of this particular page.

Here is the code as you suggested

```
      {% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
      {% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}

      {% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
      {{ media }}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}">{% endblock %}

      {% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}

      {% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-form{% endblock %}

      {% if not is_popup %}
      {% block breadcrumbs %}
      <div class="breadcrumbs">
      <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
      &rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
      &rsaquo; {% if has_view_permission %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}{% endif %}
      &rsaquo; {% if add %}{% blocktrans with name=opts.verbose_name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}{% else %}{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}{% endif %}
      </div>
      {% endblock %}
      {% endif %}

      {% block content %}<div id="content-main">
      {% block object-tools %}
      {% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
        <ul class="object-tools">
          {% block object-tools-items %}
            {% change_form_object_tools %}
          {% endblock %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}{% endif %}
      {% endblock %}
      <form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
      <div>
      {% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ is_popup_var }}" value="1">{% endif %}
      {% if to_field %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ to_field_var }}" value="{{ to_field }}">{% endif %}
      {% if save_on_top %}{% block submit_buttons_top %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}{% endif %}
      {% if errors %}
          <p class="errornote">
          {% if errors|length == 1 %}{% trans "Please correct the error below." %}{% else %}{% trans "Please correct the errors below." %}{% endif %}
          </p>
          {{ adminform.form.non_field_errors }}
      {% endif %}

      {% block field_sets %}
      {% for fieldset in adminform %}
        {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block after_field_sets %}{% endblock %}

      {% block inline_field_sets %}
      {% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
          {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endblock %}

      {% block after_related_objects %}{% endblock %}

      {% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}

      {% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
          <script type="text/javascript"
                  id="django-admin-form-add-constants"
                  src="{% static 'admin/js/change_form.js' %}"
                  {% if adminform and add %}
                      data-model-name="{{ opts.model_name }}"
                  {% endif %}>
          </script>
      {% endblock %}

      {# JavaScript for prepopulated fields #}
      {% prepopulated_fields_js %}

      </div>
      </form></div>
      {% endblock %}
```

```
<form id="fontsize-form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <label class="control-label">Arabic:</label>
        <div class="controls"><input id="pw" type="text"></div>

        <div class="control-group" style="display:none" id="passwordfield">
                <label class="control-label">English:</label>

                <div class="controls"><input id="pw" type="text"></div>
            </div>

    </form>


    <div >
        <button class="button" onclick="showPWField()">+</button>
        <script>
            function showPWField() {
                document.getElementById("passwordfield").style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
    </div>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy if from your virtual environment `lib>python3.6>site-packages>django>contrib>admin>templates>admin>change_form.html`

into

`my_app>templates>admin>model_name>change_form.html`

And edit

Comment: Here's the code for that page. But I can't understand where to edit what I've have to.. I basically want to place a button in front of a specific field. I cant find the HTML of that specific field where I can add my own Button.

Comment: Because these templates are coded without using the field names so they are generic for all applications.  Just try putting some text into the page and see where it shows when you view it through the admin site.  Keep adjusting until you've found where you want it and then create your button